# Rename pandas Dataframe Column With Data Under it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this :

```
df_data
```

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| January | February | March |
| 100 | 200 | 300 |

I Want to change the column name to something like this by increasing the contents of the dataframe from the first index

```
df_data
```

| January | February | March |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 300 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert first line to columns names and then filter out first line of DataFrame by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:].rename_axis(columns=None)
print (df)
  January February March
1     100      200   300
```

For one line solution:

```
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).iloc[1:].rename_axis(columns=None)
print (df)
  January February March
1     100      200   300
```